# Unity only working at one object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problem, that when I have more than one door in my scene, a text appears only when I am near to one of the doors. I really dont know where is the problem, because Unity dont throw any exception. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject doorBody;
    Transform player;
    private AudioSource doorSound;
    public float doorOpenAngle = 90.0f;
    public float doorCloseAngle = 0.0f;
    public float doorAnimSpeed = 2.0f;
    private Quaternion doorOpen = Quaternion.identity;
    private Quaternion doorClose = Quaternion.identity;
    private Transform playerTrans = null;
    public bool doorStatus = false; //false = close, true = open
    private bool doorGo = false;
    public Text text;

    void Start()
    {
        doorStatus = false; //door is open
        doorSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        doorOpen = Quaternion.Euler(0, doorOpenAngle, 0);
        doorClose = Quaternion.Euler(0, doorCloseAngle, 0);
        playerTrans = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
        text.text = "";
    }
    void Update()
    {
            if (Vector3.Distance(playerTrans.position, this.transform.position) < 2f)
            {
            text.text = "Press 'E' to use";
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !doorGo)
                {
                    doorBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
                    doorSound.mute = false;
                    if (doorStatus)
                    { //close door
                        StartCoroutine(this.moveDoor(doorClose));
                        doorSound.Play();
                    }
                    else { //open door
                        StartCoroutine(this.moveDoor(doorOpen));
                        doorSound.Play();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            text.text = "";
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator moveDoor(Quaternion dest)
    {
        doorGo = true;
        while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.localRotation, dest) > 4.0f)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, dest, Time.deltaTime * doorAnimSpeed);
            yield return null;
        }
        //Change door status
        doorBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        doorStatus = !doorStatus;
        doorGo = false;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Tank you.

Comment: Is the script attached to the prefab object or each individual door?

Comment: Yes, it is.................

Comment: Your scripts doesn't seems to have problems and if it works for one instance of your prefab it must work for all unless you changed something on one of the instances after place. So, without see your prefab structure and the comparison between both instances will be very hard to identify what is the problem...

Comment: Just a "side note": You really need to compare the distance between each door that you have in your scene with player position every single frame? Why you don't use a simple trigger to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you only have the script attatched to one of the door ojects. Check that you have attatched the script to both doors.

If the problem is not with that, then the other area that might be causing an issue is

```
            if (Vector3.Distance(playerTrans.position, this.transform.position) < 2f)
            {
            text.text = "Press 'E' to use";
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !doorGo)
                {
                    doorBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
                    doorSound.mute = false;
                    if (doorStatus)
                    { //close door
                        StartCoroutine(this.moveDoor(doorClose));
                        doorSound.Play();
                    }
                    else { //open door
                        StartCoroutine(this.moveDoor(doorOpen));
                        doorSound.Play();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            text.text = "";
```

The else part may be causing the text to be set to NULL when you dont want it to be. For example, if you go to one of the two doors the if statement of that door will be true and the text will display, and then when you walk away from the first door the code will go to else and set the text to NULL. Then when you walk to the second door, the new door will try to set the text to the correct string, but the first door code will be overriding it and setting the text to NULL.

If that is the problem, then the best solution would most likely be to switch the door proximity detection code over to the player. That way instead of each door constantly checking every update to see if a player is in range, the player itself will simply check if any doors are in range.

Comment: Jessy final concern matches with my comment above about the "crude" way that the moment for display the text is taken.... you really should learn about triggers and there is a lot of tutorial about opening doors with triggers over the internet...

Comment: Yes there are much better ways of checking for this than calculating the distance between door and player every frame.

Comment: I know about other ways how to do that, but i wrote this script just for test and I will edit it a lot :) However thank you a lot for your answers!

Comment: Keyword `Trigger`.